# О значении слова "создание"

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

*Есть предложение: Но как же не похожа была эта церковь на простые и ясные **создания, устроенные** Саввой.*

Речь идет о монастырях, в создании которых принимал участие Савва Сербский, религиозный, культурный и политический деятель.

Выражение ***создания, устроенные*** показалось мне не очень подходящим, хотя у слова *создание* есть значение "то, что создано; произведение, творение".

А чем заменить? Вариант вроде бы нашелся, но точно ли он лучше? И как объяснить причину замены?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменить можно так: *сооружения*. Тут задумано показать усилия, вложенные в своё творение, за счёт связи с глаголом (*создать, соорудить, творить*).

*Простые и ясные монастыри* — как-то так люди не говорят.

На мой взгляд, в этом значении вместо данного слова часто употребляют слово "*творение*". "*Создание*" чаще применяется в третьем значении — что-то живое.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне хотелось бы увидеть в нем полный текст вашего варианта предложения, где сделана замена двух выделенных слов. И узнать ваше мнение об авторском варианте. Надо его заменять или можно оставить? Мне надо написать: "творения, устроенные Саввой"?  Как-то не очень звучит.

Comment: *Но как же не похожа была эта церковь на простые и ясные сооружения, построенные Саввой.* Наверно, можно оставить: здесь есть церковные нотки - Бог создал окружающий мир, а храмы - создания Саввы во имя Господа; окружающий мир устроен Богом, а Савва устраивает что-то по его канонам, подражая ему. Хоть оно и не очень звучит. Какую-то такую связь вижу в этих словах - игра слов.

Comment: Церковь как-то не очень похожа на сооружение, это же не крепость.  А чем не подходит авторский вариант, назовите причину.

Comment: *Из словаря: сооружение - то, что сооружено; постройка, строение (различного вида и назначения).*  У меня тоже не звучит, как и у вас. Причина: третий абзац и *устраивать* - больше обуславливать что-то, а здесь явно значение *построенные*. Нельзя сказать, что можно устроить монастырь.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо за участие.  В принципе у меня есть вариант, оставлю пока его. А давайте поиграем в слова для интереса (интерес с вознаграждением). Угадайте это сочетание, подсказка такая: оба слова начинаются на С.

Comment: *Сооружённые создания (созданные сооружения)*? Ни одно из этих слов?

Comment: Одно слово угадано.

Comment: А какое? Мне же нужно знать, чтобы искать второе, не выкидывая первое.

Comment: Это - слово "созданные".

Comment: *Соборы, святыни*?

Comment: Но как же не похожа была эта церковь на простые и ясные с........я, созданные Саввой.

Comment: Сотворения? Не думаю, что тавтология с "создания".

Comment: Всё намного проще. Придется вам дать задание на дом. Кстати, слово упоминается в комментариях, но не как замена.

Comment: Аа. Строения.__

Comment: Вот теперь правильно, ну и как вам вариант?

Comment: Вроде бы нормально.

Comment: Спасибо, мне нравится эта фраза. Про нее анекдот смешной есть. До новых встреч на форуме.